# Escape hex character in string

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

I executed a function in Python on Windows that returned this string:

```
p = subprocess(args=["devenv.exe", "project.sln"], ...)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
print(stdout) # b'unzul\x84ssig'
```

This is supposed to be called `unzulässig`. I am wondering which decoder I need to use to convert it back to the word. `string_escape` nor `utf8`(of course not) did work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: convert to an actual string, not bytes object

Comment: But I need the encoding for that

Comment: If I'd had to guess I'd say it's something like "extended ASCII", which unfortunately doesn't actually mean anything. It would help if you told us how you got that string.

Comment: `b'unzul\xc3\xa4ssig'.decode('utf-8') == 'unzulässig'`

Comment: You are supposed to "know" which decoder to use for your incoming data; it's not something you can infer. Are you sure it's `\x84`? Most common encodings (iso-8859, cp-1252, etc) map `ä` to `\xe4`.

Comment: @hansolo sorry, that's unrelated, its not what I receive. You can't simply change the return value of a function :-D

Comment: It is coming from the stdout of `subprocess.Popen("devenv.com",..)` which is the VS compiler

Comment: IBM437 and IBM850 are [possible candidates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Latin_character_sets_(computing)#Comparison_table)…

Comment: Also, you might try to use  ` shell=False` for the call to "Popen" - which will likely avoid the subprocess encoding its output in arcane XX century manufactorer-ad-hoc encodings still embalmed into Microsoft's cmd.

Comment: In Windows you can use the `chcp` command at a prompt to find out what the command shell uses for a code page.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you may want [code page 858](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_858):

```
>>> "unzulässig".encode('858')
b'unzul\x84ssig'
```

So

```
>>> res = b'unzul\x84ssig'
>>> res.decode('858')
'unzulässig'
```

As @deceze pointed out in a comment, IBM437 and IBM850 are also possibilities.

```
>>> res.decode('ibm437')
'unzulässig'
>>> res.decode('ibm850')
'unzulässig'
```

There is lots of overlap between various character sets, but based on this small sample, all we can do is suggest ones that are known to map `'ä'` to `b'\x84'`. For example, my original suggestion for 858 was noticing at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page that 858 was a DOS code page for Western European languages (with euro sign). There are *lots* of single-byte encodings that may be identical for most code points (even ignoring 0-127, which very often share the same ASCII roots), but may differ at select values.

Comment: Holy moly! Thanks so much! Can't accept answer yet (in 5 minutes)

Comment: It's *one* possibility among many. It may fail on different characters…

Comment: Yep, better to know the encoding from the source

Comment: also,  cp852 is a likely candidate

Comment: @DanielStephens if you use `'mbcs'` for the code page, Python will select the one that's used by your version of Windows.

Comment: `mbcs` is unfortunately not working for my string :-(

Comment: @chepner: I think it's 437 since this is the default for a command prompt. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```py
res = function().decode("cp852")
print(res) # b'unzul\x84ssig'
```

How do you know it is `cp852`? You have to know that from the documentation of your `function`, or for the data source to it. There is not such thing as 'text' if you are getting an input of bytes - you have to *know* which encoding was used to represent the desired text as those bytes.

I suggest reading https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

(In particular, under WIndows, the `cmd` window does use old DOS encoding, for being compatible with 1980 era code - A Python interpreter started from the CMD shell will probably reflect this encoding in the `sys.stdout.encoding` attribute)

Comment: Thanks! I updated my question where I got the string from

Comment: yes - `sys.stdout.encoding` is still a nice place to try to get the correct encoding from. Also, you can try using `shell=False` in the Popen call - (but that would just change the encoding to another - perhaps the one returned by `sys.getdefaultencoding()` )

Comment: Thanks for the tip. `sys.stdout.encoding` and `sys.getdefaultencoding()` unfortunately points to utf-8